# Showing that the set of natural number, $\omega$, is Dedekind infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Showing that the set of natural number, $\omega$, is Dedekind infinite. It is an easy task to show this directly by sending $n$ to $2n$, then we produces a injective map that is not surjective.

But suppose I want to make use of this fact that there is  a bijection between $\omega $ and $\omega+1 = \omega\ \cup \{\omega\}$, how might one produce an injective map from $\omega$ to $\omega$ that is not surjective ?

Cheers and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply compose a bijection $f\colon\omega+1\to\omega$ with the inclusion map $\omega\subseteq\omega+1$. In other words, simply restrict $f$ to $\omega$.

Since $\omega$ is a proper subset of $\omega+1$, the result will be an injection from $\omega$ to itself whose range is not $\omega$.

Comment: Ah! Because I need the '+1' to hit every $x \in X$ using $f$, so if I just restrict $f$, then I am bound to miss some guy. It remains injective because restriction does not affect injectivity.